# Creating picture frame by repeating a smaller image

Tags: html, image, css

I've started working on an app that does image processing and image cropping, using a library called [cropper.js](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper). Right now, I've been tasked with investigation and possible implementation of a feature that would take the cropped image and create a visual representation of how a picture frame would look like.

Example: 
[image: Example from FramedAndMatted site]

The difference is, I'm not able to use already stored images, but have to build this type of image using one piece of image that will look like this:

[image: Frame piece]

Along with that, I have to somehow cut the side of the image piece under 45 degree angle to be able to reproduce the desired effect.

How would one go about doing this? I've thought of repeating that image piece a couple of times on all four sides, and then somehow cutting the far side parts of the image under 45 degree angle, but have no idea how to go about this :(

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use a frame sprite (an image that already has the cuts) instead of a single horizontal texture?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're suggesting having a placeholder image which would represent the frame (with angle cuts), and then just filling in the frame with a specific image?

Comment: Well, sort of - that's easy to implement if you ensure that the image dimensions are the same each time, otherwise you need to create a repeatable pattern

Comment: Could you create an example? 
And yeah, image dimensions won't be the same each time, that's guaranteed. In most cases sites that have similar functionality work with already stored images of a frame and then just display it, and some of them have half a frame and then just duplicate it diagonally. In my case, I have to work with a single piece of frame, and make the whole out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way with pure CSS is taking advantage of `multiple-backgrounds` for the main frames using 2 images, one vertical and the other is horizontal.

As for the corners, you only need one image of a transparent 45 degrees cut square texture, which will be used in 4 divs, each one is flipped through `transform: scale()` and positioned to the sides using `position: absolute;`

```css
.picframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: 
    url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyp42.png'), /* top */
    url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyp42.png'), /* bottom */
    url('http://puu.sh/q3NmA/48c4271f4f.jpg'), /* left */
    url('http://puu.sh/q3NmA/48c4271f4f.jpg'); /* right */
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-y;
    background-position: top left, bottom left, top left, top right;
}

.picframe [class^="corner"] {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ixUr.png) no-repeat;
  height: 62px; width: 62px;
  position: absolute;
}

.picframe .corner-t-l {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.picframe .corner-t-r {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: scale(-1,1);
}

.picframe .corner-b-l {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(1,-1);
}

.picframe .corner-b-r {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: scale(-1,-1);
}
```

```html
<div class="picframe">
  <div class="corner-t-l"></div>
  <div class="corner-t-r"></div>
  <div class="corner-b-l"></div>
  <div class="corner-b-r"></div>
</div>
```

**Pros:**

- Easy to implement
- Responsive
- Minimal code

**Cons:**

- Might not be the most accurate
- Requires creation of 3 images: [vertical](http://puu.sh/q3NmA/48c4271f4f.jpg), [horizontal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyp42.png), [corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ixUr.png)
- Requires knowledge of frame size (for corners height/width)

---

If a one-piece texture is your only option, then you can flip the background by using CSS transform (90 degrees rotation or mirroring with negative scale `scale(1,-1)` for the main frames (top, bottom, left, right).

The corners are bit more complicated and can be done by making a div that is rotated 45 degrees and has a child or pseudo selector inside that reverses the parent's rotation then applies the background, then hiding the excess with `overflow: hidden` on the parent corner container:

```css
:root {
  --frame-size: 160px;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

[class^="frame"] {
  background: url("https://i.gyazo.com/6836b6d12cebf4b0fd9a2758ad3a04a9.png");
  position: absolute;
  /*outline:1px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.5);*/
}

.frame--top,
.frame--bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--frame-size);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.frame--bottom {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: scale(1, -1);
}

/* optional shading for realism */
.frame--top::after,
.frame--bottom::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.frame--left,
.frame--right {
  height: var(--frame-size);
  width: calc( 100vh - (var(--frame-size)*2));
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.frame--right {
  bottom: var(--frame-size);
  right: var(--frame-size);
  left: auto;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

[class^="frame--corner"] {
  height: calc(var(--frame-size)* 1);
  width: calc(var(--frame-size) * 1.425);
  background: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

[class^="frame--corner"]::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  right: 0;
  top: -50%;
}

.frame--corner--tr,
.frame--corner--br {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}

.frame--corner--tr::before,
.frame--corner--br::before {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="frame--top">
  <div class="frame--corner--tl"></div>
  <div class="frame--corner--tr"></div>
</div>
<div class="frame--bottom">
  <div class="frame--corner--bl"></div>
  <div class="frame--corner--br"></div>
</div>
<div class="frame--left"></div>
<div class="frame--right"></div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/cb7feu5p/2/

**Pros:**

- Single image (texture)
- Responsive
- Frame size can be dynamic

**Cons:**

- Might not be the most accurate
- Larger amount of code and 8 HTML tags

For this to work as pure CSS, many calculations use a CSS variable (`--frame-size`), please be sure to check browser compatibility for CSS variables, transforms and `calc()` expressions. Otherwise, you will need to run all these operations through JavaScript.

Comment: And also, I just noticed that the all 4 sides of the frame need to be mirror images of the opposing side. I noticed that they weren't when I applied a different image. https://jsfiddle.net/xojd1zqe/5/

Comment: @MilanStojanovic good observation, I've totally missed that fact. Please see my updated answer with refined code.

Comment: This is absolutely amazing! As you mentioned, I would have to do some of these calculations from JS, but I've already applied this solution to the app, and it works wonderful with custom images!

Comment: Sometimes, because of different dimension of image, I am getting strange results. With bigger image, frame gets too large (see i.imgur.com/IHAEcPW.jpg). Is it possible to scale down the image to predefined height, while keeping the aspect ratio? Also, it may need to be repeated to fill the frame, is it possible to use something like border-image with repeat?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the border-image property for this, it should work perfectly for what you're trying to do. It will use the corners of the image for the corners, and will stretch or repeat what is in-between. You can also define the border-width for each border as normal.

The advantage to this method is that it works just like any normal border, therefore there is no worry about scaling or keeping the content always the same size, it will adapt nicely according to the content.

This is how the code would look like, excluding extra code for full browser support:

```
border-image: url("border.png") 27 fill repeat;
```

Here's some handy links for browser support & guides:

http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image (I think partial support issues will not be relevant to your case though, as long as you use the shorthand)

https://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

This site makes it really easy to define your borders from the images, as it can be a bit of a pain to count it all manually:
http://border-image.com/

Comment: Interesting, I have thought about this but I don't think it allows you to create a 45 degrees cut in the corners, unless you create a special image/sprite, which the OP cannot do. Care to create a basic demo?

Comment: I think I misread that part then, I thought he meant he might need to create the images/didn't know how. If he can't create the "sprite" and can only always use the one-piece image, I don't think its possible to do this using border-image alone.